# How To Store Swift function in a variable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, polymorphism, closures

```
// Assume you have two functions.
// Swift considers these functions as distinct
func cars(left look: String) {}
func cars(right look: String) {}

// How can I store them in a variable for later use?
let c: (left : String) -> ()  = cars
let c2: (right : String) -> () = cars
```

When I try to store these methods into a variable, I get an error stating that "cars" is ambiguous.  What can I do to differentiate them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to help the compiler decide which function you want because it does not distinguish between parameter names when deciding if a function's signature is valid for assignment.

You can disambiguate your intent by being specific on the parameter names

```
let c:  (left :String) -> () = cars(left:)
let c2: (right:String) -> () = cars(right:)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two functions have the same set of parameters, string.
To be able to have a polymorphic function, each function must have
a different set of [parameter types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).

```
func cars( look: String) {}
func cars( look: Int) {}
```

You were able to get away from the compiler by adding left and right
description which is the preferred style for Objective-C but not for swift.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have 2 functions with the same name which you cannot change

```
func cars(left look: String) { print(0) }
func cars(right look: String) { print(1) }
```

and you need to store them into 2 variables you could follow this approach

```
let c0: (left : String) -> () = { cars(left:$0) }
let c1: (right : String) -> () = { cars(right:$0) }
```

> As you can see I created 2 closures, they call respectively the first and the second one function.

### Test

```
c0(left: "") // 0
c1(right: "") // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func cars(left look: String) {}
func cars(right look: String) -> Int { return look.count }

var c:  (_ left :String) -> () = cars(left:)
var c2: (_ right:String) -> Int = cars(right:)

// Uses
print(c2("test"))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**